# Issue with PanGestureRecognizer's value

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on a system where a PanGestureRecognizer uses a series of if statements to move a button to one of several different places as follows:

```
(IBAction)drag: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if (touchLocation.x > -12.5 && touchLocation.x < 27.5)
    {
        recognizer.view.center= CGPointMake(30, 486);
    }

    else if (touchLocation.x > 32.5 && touchLocation.x < 72.5)
    {
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(75, 486);

    }

...
```

The problem I'm running into is that when touchLocation begins on the right side of the button (to be dragged to the right) the coordinates of the PanGesture begin late, and the piece moves late. When the players touch begins on the left side of the button, the coordinates count up correctly and the piece acts as it should.

I'm still a complete newb when it comes to programming so this may not even be the most efficient way to get my piece to move in the first place, but I have this so close to working and I feel like all I need is one more piece to get my code working as desired. Please let me know what you think!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`translationInView` provides the offset from the touch location, perhaps you want to use [`locationInView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) to get the actual touch location?